# Error in creating new Clojure project in eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, clojure

I have installed jdk1.8 and counterclockwise plugin for clojure in eclipse neon.
But when i am trying to create new clojure project, i am getting 'Exception while creating new project unable to find valid certification path to requested target
' error and project is not getting created.
Other projects are getting created properly. And clojure plugin is also installed properly. I have proxy setting on my machine so is this error related to proxy?

Comment: Thanks. I tried in eclipse mars 2.0 also, but got same error.

Comment: Just for the record, CounterClockwise development has been in maintenance mode for some time. The error you are getting seems to be related to SSL, so it might be a https proxy issue, or a cert issue like mentioned here https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification . It might have to do with the SSLication of most of the Clojure infrastructure, like the Clojars repositories. Do you run into the same problems while doing a `lein new <projectname>` command ?

Comment: No, i am able to create project using command lein new <projectname>.